# Terminate a Docker process launched with Qt

Tags: windows, qt, docker

In my application I launch a QProcess that initiates a Docker container, which runs a long execution with this:

```
QString path = "C:/Windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe";
QString commands = "docker run --rm --user user --workdir /tmp/project -v C:/Users/user/project:/tmp/project ofubuntu /tmp/project/script.sh";
process->start(path, commands.split(" "));
```

Sometimes the Qt application is closed before the QProcess finishes, what leaves a "Vmmem" process running in Windows.

If tried to kill the QProcess on CloseEvent with:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event){
    process->kill();
}
```

However it does not have the desired effect. Instead, the process vmmem in the operating system is still running until it finishes.

What I do to terminate the launched processes is to restart the Docker daemon, but I do not consider that a proper approach.

How could I kill all the processes launched (and their children) from my Qt application before exiting?

Comment: What if you call `process->waitForFinished()` after calling `process->kill()`. Will your application wait forever?

Comment: The process in the operating system is still running until it ends the execution. I'd like to kill it immediately, instead.

Comment: I would suggest, that rather calling kill you should try to start a new `QProcess` with an appropriate `docker stop` command. After all, it seems to be a sane way to quit a docker process.

Comment: I've tried with a QProcess executing "docker kill <container-id>", but it doesn't have any effect on the container.

Comment: What about `docker stop`? Did you checked, that you issued the right options? You should consider to do `process->setStandardOutputFile("out.txt");` and `process->setStandardErrorFile("err.txt");`to see possible helpful output.

Comment: It seems to work!

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: @Aleph0 yes, I've been testing it and stop works better than kill.